# Error in PHP 7.4 - imagecolorallocate - milon / barcode

Tags: laravel, barcode

[Solved]

I'm using the repo milon/barcode (v7.0.1) in a Laravel (v7.30.4) application, and yesterday, after updated my server to 7.4.16 (Centos8) , I have got this error:

"Trying to access array offset on value of type bool"

I already checked if the GD PHP extension was enabled (and it is), and I can't find how to solve this.

```
 if (function_exists('imagecreate')) {

        // GD library

        $imagick = false;

        $png = imagecreate($width, $height);

        $bgcol = imagecolorallocate($png, 255, 255, 255);

        imagecolortransparent($png, $bgcol);

        $fgcol = imagecolorallocate($png, $color[0], $color[1], $color[2]);
```

Function: getBarcodePNG

Line: 186
$fgcol = imagecolorallocate($png, $color[0], $color[1], $color[2]);

I think it is a server/php error, but I'm not good in server things :(

Thanks

Comment: And what have you tried to resolve this error?

Comment: Hi Nico. A lot of things. I checked the PHP GD version, installed the most recent packages, but I get always this error

Comment: Please share more details - for example, what do these variables contain? What have you tried to debug the problem? And how is this related to Laravel, or the very broad tag [tag:barcode]?

Comment: Hi Nico, I updated the text. Thank you

Comment: Still: what have you tried to debug the problem? Have you even tried to check what `$color` contains? The given code does not contain the definition of that variable

Answer (score 0):

For who are facing the same issue:

In PHP 7.4, is **mandatory** to pass all the parameters to the getBarcodePNG function